# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am receiving this error. I am using Python 3.6.5.

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char
>   1)

mycode is here:

```
import json 

filename = 'btc_close_2017.json'
with open(filename) as f:
    btc_data = json.load(f)


for btc_dict in btc_data:
    date = btc_dict['date']
    month = int(btc_dict['month'])
    week = int(btc_dict['week'])
    weekday = btc_dict['weekday']
    close = int(float(btc_dict['close'])) 
    print("{} is month {} week {}, {}, the close price is {} RMB".format(
        date, month, week, weekday, close))
```

Comment: Please show us the JSON content. Seems like maybe the JSON is not valid.

Comment: Seems like maybe the 2nd line of the JSON is not valid.

Comment: The json file is wrong,problem is solved